# Нет функции gtk_check_button_get_active()

Tags: c, функции, виджет, gtk

Хочу забрать состояние виджета `CheckButton` с помощью функции `gtk_check_button_get_active()`, однако такая функция не находится. Для других виджетов подобная функция имеется и работает корректно.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Версия у вас какая?

Comment: @ori GTK? - 3.2

Comment: А доступность с 4й

Comment: @ori Странно, на PythonGTK эта функция имеется в виде метода для виджета кнопки, версия, вроде, та же

Comment: @ori , проблему решил, спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Для GTK 3.0

**Проблему решил так:**

Как сказано в [руководстве](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/button_widgets.html#checkbutton), `Gtk.CheckButton` наследуется от `Gtk.ToggleButton`, следовательно `gtk_toggle_button_set_active()` и `gtk_toggle_button_get_active()` наследуются тоже.

По итогу, такая функция `gtk_toggle_button_get_active(check_btn)` корректно возвращает статус кнопки, хоть IDE и подсвечивает аргумент `check_btn`, как несовместимый тип.
Если хотите, чтобы при сборке не выдавало предупреждений - сделайте приведение типов таким образом `gtk_toggle_button_get_active((GtkToggleButton *) check_btn)`

### Для GTK 4.0

В GTK 4.0 для `Gtk.CheckButton` добавлены собственные функции `gtk_check_button_get_active()` и `gtk_check_button_set_active()`